# tpm-emulator-master.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory?

Tags: linux, unix, tar

Can't figure out the problem as im a newbie to linux:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ tar -xvzf tpm-emulator-master.X.Y.tar.gz
tar (child): tpm-emulator-master.X.Y.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or       directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ls
tpm-emulator-master  ubiquity.desktop
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the file you are trying to untar is not in the directory you are in.
Either you have already un-tar'd the file (and removed it) and/or the contents are in the `tpm-emulator-master` folder.

Use the `cd` command to **C**hange **D**irectory into the `tpm-emulator-master` folder

```
cd tpm-emulator-master
```

Comment: i didn't untar it, plus im in the right directory check another one :
>ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ tar -xvzf tpm_emulator-0.7.4.X.Y.tar.gz
>tar (child): tpm_emulator-0.7.4.X.Y.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
>tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>tar: Child returned status 2
>tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ls
>ibmtss1234.tar.gz  tpm_emulator  tpm_emulator-0.7.4.tar.gz'

Comment: Is it possible that you downloaded or saved the file without the tar.gz extension? Linux is very literal, if the tpm-emulator-master is not a directory try renaming it using 'mv'.  You can type 'man mv' to get instructions on using mv.   Either way, would you please post the output of 'ls -lah' in the directory in which you have this tar file?

Comment: just checked , yes i figured its .zip i downloaded it from here https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator and im following the steps from the Readme yet can't figure out the solution. Apreciate your help

Comment: You are correct, if you downloaded it as a .zip from github, tar will absolutely not extract it and the README in github is incorrect. 
 Depending on your linux distro, the program 'unzip' may already be present, try 'unzip tpm-emulator-master'

Comment: succefully unziped but faced lot of issues executing commands from readme,im lost in a loop :/ could be incorrect?